# After pressing home button new Instance of application starts . How to avoid to create multiple instance of Application

Tags: android, multiple-instances

I am  facing an issue that ,When ever I start the app and press home button  ,then again I click the apps icon a new instance of that app is created . How to solve this issue ?

My Manifest file as follows  ,

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mytast.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 

         android:screenOrientation="portrait"

         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

          android:alwaysRetainTaskState="True"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.example.mytast.MainActivity"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   ...
   >  
</activity>
```

and remove:

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

from the directive.

Comment: Maybe change the directive to `android:launchMode=singleTop` or another value and see if it works.